# Is it possible to bake vector displacement maps from a sculpted object?

Tags: rendering, displacement

I'd like to achieve the same thing as this video tutorial shows with [Mudbox + Maya + Redshift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gbk8vT_p8sg), baking a high poly sculpt onto a plane. I'm not looking for regular displacement as it only moves geometry along normals.

Would this be possible in Blender ? If so, could you explain how to make this ?

I found a few videos about vector displacement in Blender, but it's mostly demos and none gave insight about how one could make this.

Comment: You can use this node group: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dgrz7_Xl5Eo

Comment: Thanks a lot, that should really help me.